# How to restrict Import & Export functions to a specified path?

Tags: export, import, security

We're providing Mathematica computing service to our customers. Now we're decided introducing `Import` and `Export` functions, but with file path restriction.

Supposing the base secure path is : `/allowed/path/`

When

- `Export["test.gif", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]` the `test.gif` goes to `/allowed/path/test.gif`
- `Export["plot/test.gif", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]` the `test.gif` goes to `/allowed/path/plot/test.gif`

And `Export["/somewhere/else/test.gif", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]` is prohibited.

`Import` function should match the same role.

Currently I'm thinking to rewrite `Import` & `Export`. But is it possible to do this in Mathematica ?

Comment: Have a look at `SetDirectory[]`.

Comment: Why not simply write a wapper that checks the path?  And call the wrapper instead. `myExport[path_,....]:=Module[{},...If[path==theOkOne,.. Export[...], Throw["No way!"]];` This seems to me to be simpler than rewriting the while Export and Import functions from scratch?